# How to duplicate the public Bower registry?

Tags: javascript, bower

How to dump/replicate the content of the public Bower registry ?

The web has many resource about how to do so with the public npm registry, but nothing relevant enough for the public Bower registry; however, the need for an offline backup still apply.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing. Bower just fetches git repos. But I've never used bower, so don't count on me.

Comment: Could you not just do `bower search` (with no additional args, making it list all packages) and feed the results (which might require some light pre-processing) to `bower install`?

Comment: Also see this https://github.com/bower/bower#using-bowers-cache

Comment: ajp15243 your answer is correct. Can you post it as an answer please, instead of comment ? Prinzhorn yes but I want to host my own couchDB behind my own REST API, just as the real public Bower registry works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run

```
bower search
```

without any additional arguments, then Bower will list all available packages in its registry. You will probably have to do a little bit of pre-processing on the output, but you can then feed this list to `bower install` to install each package in turn.  How you do this is up to you (NodeJS, shell script, etc.).

You may want to have a Bower configuration wherever you run this that specifies where to store your backup of the registry. Make sure you have ample disk space -- this is likely going to take up a lot. It will also probably take a while to download even on a fast network connection, so it might be an overnight or during the day while you do something else kind of operation.

To update your backup, I imagine the same idea can be used, except replace `bower install` with `bower update`.